# Using the time from chronometer widget to calculate amount given a rate

Tags: android, time, chronometer

I am using the Chronometer widget to get time elapsed. It has a `ticklistener` to perform an action when the time changes. I need to calculate an amount using `rate*time` while the time is running but I do not know how to get the exact seconds elapsed while the chronometer is running. Can anyone point me the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The chronometer calculates time in `milliseconds` as specified in this [link](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/chronometeronchronometerticklistener.html) using the `onChronometerTickListener` so this needs to be converted to seconds by multiplying the time elapsed by `0.001`. Now, you have the total time elapsed in seconds and you can perform any computations on it.

```
        double amount;
        string precision;

        timer.start();
        timer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                long myElapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timer.getBase();
                double seconds = myElapsedMillis * 0.001;
                amount = (seconds/3600)* hourlyRate;
                precision = new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(amount);                    
            }
        });
```